# React native xcode debug and release scheme two different builds

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I have a react native project and when the schema in XCode is set to debug the project builds with the latest code changes I added. When I change the scheme to release the release build doesn't have the latest code changes.

Why is this this happening is there a setting that I have to change from debug to release to get the latest changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normaly no,

Try to remove ios/build and re-build in release mode.

Check in Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme -> if you are in release mode enable and debug executable unchecked.

Can you tell me more about the code difference between debug and release on your project?

Regards.

Comment: I tried to clean and rebuild and checked the scheme but no luck. I just added a new page to my react native app.